# Word Spacing Query

Tags: css

I have a word spacing issue which I cannot seem to resolve.

The web page is www.c5d.co.uk/captaintwo.php

The word spacing under the top images look ridiculous. Yet as far as I can see, the CSS is the same.

What am I missing ?  If I put a /p tag after Wrigley it works fine but fails validation as there is no opening p tag

Relevant HTML and CSS is as follows:

```
.captain{word-spacing:185px;display:inline;} 
.pres {display:inline; }
.ladycaptain{word-spacing:120px;display:inline; }  



  <img class="lewis" src="http://www.c5d.co.uk/captain.png" alt="The Captain">
  <img class="socialtwo" src="http://www.c5d.co.uk/president.png" alt="President">
  <p class="pres">
  <br>Captain: John</p> <p class="captain">Lewis President:</p> Bill Wrigley
  <img class="lewis" src="http://www.c5d.co.uk/ladycaptain.png" alt="Lady Captain">
  <img class="socialtwo" src="http://www.c5d.co.uk/juniorcaptain.png" alt="Junior Captain">
  <p class="pres">
  <br>Lady Captain: Beryl</p> <p class="ladycaptain">Harrison Junior</p> Captain: Kieran Metcalf
```

Comment: I do need some help because what I have done seems to have made it worse not better. 

I am sure that I have done what you instructed 

.captain{display:inline-block; width:270px; text-align:center;} 
.pres {display:inline-block; width:270px; text-align:center;}

But it now gives three sort of sections

Comment: You mean in the class .ladycaptain ?

Comment: It's nearly there. The top works fine but the bottom pictures do not have the text underneath them. Do I need to put the wordspacing back there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the following changes:

```
.pres {
    /* display: inline (remove) */
    display: inline-block;
    width: 270px;
    text-align: center;
}

.captain {
    /* display: inline (remove) */
    display: inline-block;
    width: 270px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`<br>` is outdated. Use the self-closing `<br />` instead. The names should be wrapped in something (p, span, h3, something). There are 2 styles (one inline (inside the document) and one attached to #header) that are adding around 500px of space there. That's why there is a large gap.

Consider making it easier on yourself.. use 1 class to define each TYPE of object.

```
#people {
  styles for container div
}
.box {
  styles for the individual boxes
}
.photo {
  styles for <img>
}
.title {
  styles for names of people
}
```

Then just apply the classes to the appropriate item like so

```
<div id="people"> 
  <div class="box">
    <img src="path/image.jpg" class="photo" />
      <h3 class="title">Position, name</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="path/image.jpg" class="photo" />
      <h3 class="title">Position, name</h3>
  </div>
  etc...
</div>
```

Comment: Then why is there no gap under the second set of images ? 

And incidentally, I thought that with this Doc Type <!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en"><head> <meta charset="utf-8">

<br> was fine.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by gap. You could set a `padding-bottom:` to `.title` and make them separate. It's always important to use web standards. Validation is vital.